# BJT NPN transistor

Tags: bjt, npn, semiconductors

I am confused on a topic regarding NPN BJT transistors.
[image]

When there is a collector-emitter voltage (VCE) applied to the NPN transistor (as shown in the figure) without a emitter-base voltage (VBE), it is said that this forward biases the emitter-base junction (J1) and reverse biases the base-emitter junction (J2). My confusion arises when J1 is said to be forward biased, does this mean the depletion region at J1 is reducing in size since the collector is at a lower potential and electrons are entering the depletion region due to the negative terminal of the battery. When I think of forward biasing a PN junction, the depletion region reduces until it fully 'disappears' at 0.7V (for silicon). If the depletion region is slowly decreasing, doesn't this mean some electrons can enter into the P base region?

Apologies for the simple question, just slightly confused.

Thanks

Edit: Where I have written 'it is said', I am referring to Fundamentals
of Power Semiconductor Devices page 528 by Baliga.

Comment: Can you draw out the charge density curve for the NPN without the battery? Also, draw out the electric field intensity curve? These help a lot in thinking about what happens when you apply an external field.

Comment: "it is said".  _Who_ said that?  Please _edit your question_ to include a link to a web page, or a book.

Comment: I have added the reference to the post

Comment: "reverse biases the emitter-collector junction" - hard to believe it says that.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I meant to say base-collector

Comment: @Umar [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S4Cr.png)'s what I was trying to suggest earlier. It's for a diode. But you can see the diagrams there. If you imagine a thin base junction and set up a pair of these diagrams next to each other you'll have an NPN. You can then consider what happens when an EMF is presented between the two ends, collector and emitter.

Comment: @jonk The link goes to the band diagram of an NPN: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NPN_Band_Diagram_Equilibrium.svg. I drew the charge distribution and electric fields before but I cannot insert an image. I understand how the band diagrams were formed in equilibrium (fermi level needs to be constant), which causes a depletion layer on both junctions. If I apply a collector-emitter voltage, this 'pulls up' the band of the emitter (E=-qv) and 'pulls down' further the collector band. Is this the correct way of thinking about it?

Comment: @Umar Not sure. With the applied field, the direction of the gradient at the emitter will tend to pull down (if positive is up) the previously neutral emitter bulk and thereby flatten down the positive density at the emitter's side of the depletion area -- narrowing the region of course. The direction of the gradient at the collector will tend to pull up (positive is up) the previously neutral collector bulk, further lifting and widening the barrier there. If you use paint or any program like that, you can copy it to the clipboard and paste directly into your question. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

When you apply a voltage across the emitter and collector, you are creating an electric field across the entire length of the transistor.  Since this electric field is in opposition to the built-in field in the base-emitter junction, it reduces the amount of drift and the depletion region narrows.  The opposite is true at the base-collector junction.